# Comment traduire ザワザワ (zawazawa), onomatopée japonaise désignant un bruit de foule ?

Tags: japonais, onomatopées

La langue japonaise dispose d'une onomatopée pour représenter le brouhaha, le tohu-bohu, le bruit confus produit par une foule. Il s'agit de ザワザワ (zawazawa). On la trouve souvent dans les mangas. Je suis à la recherche d'une onomatopée qui évoquerait ce tumulte, ce bourdonnement de la foule, pour l'utiliser dans des versions françaises des mangas japonais. Les suggestions sont les bienvenues !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vous voulez utiliser un terme générique, je ne vois  pas de meilleures solutions que *blabla* ou *brouhaha* déjà proposés.

Si vous désirez varier selon les cases, vous avez la possibilité d'insérer des brides de conversations ou de pensées, par exemple :

- "... acheter du pain ..." (si l'action se passe en France)
- "... quel temps! ..."
- "... il va pleuvoir ..."
- " ... rentrer à la maison ..."
- " ... le film à la télé ..."

Il me semble avoir vu ce procédé il y a longtemps dans une bande dessinée, mais je ne suis plus très sûr.

Answer (score 6):

Cela ressemble à notre *[brouhaha](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/brouhaha)*

§ ÉTYMOL. ET HIST. - 2 : "L'hyp. d'une orig. purement onomatopéique est soutenue par Mén. 1750, DG, Dauzat 1968 ..."

---

*Complément suite à la demande d’expression poétique*

En fin du § cité : « Hho, hho, hho, hho, brrrourrrourrrs, rrrourrrs, rrrourrrs. Hou, hou, hou. Hho, hho, hho. »

On doit pouvoir refléter l’ambiance de l’assemblée en jouant avec les syllabes des premiers mots employés, répétées et agencées selon le contexte :

> Une nouvelle étonnante→ «holala,  hohho, ha? ; hébééé (comme une réponse aux conséquence de l’information dominante) »
>
> Une blague → « hihi, hahahaha, hhhou-hhhouhhhouhhhou (si la blague a des conséquences sur une personne connue) »

On peut aussi y mélanger des mots désuets comme *bigre, saperlipopette* puiser dans le vocabulaire du capitaine Haddock ou des réseaux sociaux …

Comment: En effet, j'y ai déjà eu recours, merci ! Ce que je recherche est un mot qui ne se trouve pas nécessairement dans un dictionnaire tel que le TLF ou le Larousse, et qui tiendrait dans une bulle de petite taille, tout en restant lisible... Une création poétique, en quelque sorte !

Answer (score 1):

Si ce doit être utilisé dans un dessin, pourquoi ne pas utiliser "Bla bla bla ..."

Même si en général c'est plus utilisé lors d'une conversation entre 2 personnes.

Je pense que cela peut également être utilisé pour désigner le brouhaha d'une foule.

Comment: Merci pour cette suggestion. C'est en effet la solution que j'ai souvent adoptée jusqu'à présent, mais elle ne me satisfait pas entièrement, parce qu'elle évoque des sons articulés... J'aimerais trouver quelque chose qui fasse plus "bruit de fond". Ce n'est pas facile !

Comment: @missmimi je sais pas si ça te convient, mais j'ai déjà vu des "brouhaha" en onomatopées.

Comment: Merci Teleporting Goat, en effet, je m'en suis déjà servie aussi. Mais parfois il y a des tas de bulles (plus d'une dizaine) à remplir sur une même case, ce qui fait beaucoup de brouhahas ! Graphiquement, je trouve ça un peu dérangeant...

Comment: Il y a aussi des expressions comme tohu-bohu, ramdam... qui pourraient être utilisées... Mais je reste sur ma faim !